# Differents approach for validating user input and service layer commands?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

In a layered application, which a service layer waiting for commands and a Web application (asp.net MVC 3) issuing commands, I have :

```
// In the service layer
public class MyCommand
{
    public string MyVal { get; set;}
    public string AnotherProperty { get; set;}
}


// In the web layer
public class MyCommandViewModel
{
    public string MyVal { get; set;}
}
```

The viewmodel class is matching the user form, while the command class is matching the business layer requirements. As the form does not allow users to input AnotherProperty, I didn't include this property in the viewmodel.

Now I have a business rules that requires the MyVal property of my command is required and shouldn't takes more than 20 characters. In such layered application, what are guidelines for implementing such validations ?

I see several possibilities :

### 1. using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations on both classes

```
// In the service layer
public class MyCommand
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string MyVal { get; set;}
    public string AnotherProperty { get; set;}
}


// In the web layer
public class MyCommandViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string MyVal { get; set;}
}
```

this method is working, but I have to "duplicate" the validation attributes. If tomorrow, I'll have to allow 40 chars, I'll have to "find and hope none is missing" all instances of StringLength.

### 2. using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.MetadataType

The idea here, is to extract the rule in an interface (thanks to Erik Philips for the idea)

```
// In the service layer
public class IMyCommandMetaData
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string MyVal { get; set;}      
}

[MetadataType(typeof(IMyCommandMetaData))]
public class MyCommand
{     
    public string MyVal { get; set;}
    public string AnotherProperty { get; set;}
}


// In the web layer
[MetadataType(typeof(IMyCommandMetaData))]
public class MyCommandViewModel
{
    public string MyVal { get; set;}
}
```

this approach is also working. The pro is I define only once the rules, the con is that the MetadataType requires to have all properties defined on the attached object.
I have either to implement all properties in my viewmodel, even if not used, or include in the service layer only metadata properties tied to the UI (layering principle not respected).

### 3. Create specific validation attributes

Another alternative I was thinking of is to create specialized validation attributes. For example :

```
// In the service layer
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class MyValValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public MyValValidationAttribute () : base() { }
    public MyValValidationAttribute (Func<string> errorMessageAccessor) : base(errorMessageAccessor){}
    public MyValValidationAttribute (string errorMessage) : base(errorMessage) {}

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var isValid = true;
        var valueStr = value as string;
        if (valueStr != null)
        {
            isValid = valueStr.Length <= 20;
        }
        return isValid;
    }
}

public class MyCommand
{
    [Required]
    [MyValValidation]
    public string MyVal { get; set;}
    public string AnotherProperty { get; set;}
}


// In the web layer
public class MyCommandViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [MyValValidation]
    public string MyVal { get; set;}
}
```

The pro of this method, is that I can centralize the validation of one rule in one place. The con is that I have to create nearly one attribute per validation rule.

---

Another possibility is maybe to use a 3rd party validation framework instead of the OOB validation framework, but I don't see the benefits (especially because asp.net mvc use this framework to create the validation of the form).

In layered applications, with a lot of business validation rules, what would be the best options ? I'm targeting the more evolutive possible application.

Thanks in advance for comments and suggestions.

PS: this question got his source in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389635/mvc-strongly-typed-view-and-server-side-setting-properties-before-sending-to-low/7389685#7389685)