# Error while using Remote Property of DataAnnotation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model

I am having a problem using the remote property of the data-anotation.

I am having a model for user which stores the data:

```
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress,ErrorMessage="please enter valid email")]
[DisplayName("Email Address")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is Required")]
[Remote("CheckUniqueEmail","User",ErrorMessage="An account with this email address already exists.")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

and I am checking the distinct user email while creating the new one...

When I try to login with the email and password in the different controller, it still calls the Remote and checks for the unique email...

I think I have to exclude the email and password property in the Login controller - but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use another model for logging in at LoginController.

These validations will be used everywhere you use this model.

Comment: thanks... i dint know that these validation works everywhere ...thanks for sharing ...i got it working by creating ViewModel...

Answer (score 2):

you need to use 2 different view models, one for creating an account and one for logging in.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `MetadataType` to reuse the same base model and apply different validations.  Example [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276530/mvc-partial-model-updates/7276720#7276720).

Comment: thanks...i learned something new about the MetaData...never knew before... thanks for sharing...