# How to gain control over model binding?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

I started using MVC recently and I'm getting little disappointed. Instead of helping me, the framework is getting in my way.

I'm trying to write a controller action like this (pseudo code)

```
ActionResult Save(long id, string whichForm)
{
    if (whichForm == "A")
    {
        var vm = CreateModel(Request.Form);
        if (!TryValidate(vm))
            return View(vm);
        else
            return RedirectToRoute("Success");
    }
    else ....
}
```

Basically I'd like to have control over when my view-model is constructed and when it is validated. Is this possible? How can I implement CreateModel method? Consider I may want to create several different view-models within this controller action.

*Rant: I don't really understand why view-model binding and validation are mixed together in DefaultModelBinder. Seems like code smell. Specially when it's hard to override this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the downvotes, care to leave a comment ? :-)

Comment: +1 Maybe they didn't like your *Rant but you are entitled to your opinion and I see nothing wrong with the question.  If the question results in good answers, then the question is fine IMO.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can create and bind to an existing model at your discretion:

```
public ActionResult Save(long id, string whichForm)
{
    if (whichForm == "A")
    {
        var vm = new FormAViewModel();

        if (!TryUpdateModel(vm))
            return View(vm);
        else
            return RedirectToRoute("Success");
    }
    // else ....
}
```

[You also have the option of creating your own `IModelBinder`](http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/12/custom-model-binders-in-mvc-3-with-imodelbinder/), if you want complete control over the binding process. You can replace the default model binder, or you can register specific `IModelBinder` implementations for specific types. I would suggest, however, that unless your binding logic is simple, you will probably want to derive your custom model binder from `DefaultModelBinder` and just override the parts you don't like.

I hate to leave a troll-ish comment, but 9 times out of 10 the reason someone feels a framework is getting in their way is because they don't yet understand how to properly use it. [Here is an article with general tips on model binding](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx).

As to your rant: Validation and Binding are separate, however, the default model binder does trigger validation. The reason for this is to allow your application to gracefully handle problems binding to missing/invalid/incomplete values, rather than allowing binding to fail silently or throwing exceptions.

Comment: Thank you very much, I completely missed TryUpdateModel method. And believe me I have been searching for quite a while and have read all about DefaultModelBinder and IModelBinder. Also looked through MVC source code...

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage IModelBinder interface and write a complete custom model binder. Here it is explained well. Essentially, this interface exposes a method "BindModel", where you can control model binding behavior along with validation.

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=584

However, this might complicate the matter and you might get in spaghetti code. I would suggest a simple "Action per model", if it suites you. So you can write something like this :

```
ActionResult SaveA(long id, AViewModel)
{
      //.... Action to be conducted in case it is form A.
}
ActionResult SaveB(...., BViewModel)
{
       //... Action to be conducted in case it is form B.
}


// Your view models can be structured for code reuse as well.
class AViewModel {  ...  }
class BViewModel : AViewModel {  ...  }
```